# Regex for Extracting the Country Name

Tags: javascript, regex

What regular expression would extract **the country name** when used with any of the lines below?

I've got a dropdown with all of these as choices and I'm trying to extract the country only, but I'm failing miserably since JavaScript doesn't seem to support lookbehinds and I have no idea how to exclude the emoji part otherwise. (Not to mention that special characters such as that Å in Åland Islands don't make it any easier.)

Thanks!

```
 Afghanistan +93
 Åland Islands +358
 Albania +355
 Algeria +213
 American Samoa +1684
 Andorra +376
 Angola +244
 Anguilla +1264
 Antigua & Barbuda +1268
 Argentina +54
 Armenia +374
 Aruba +297
 Australia +61
 Austria +43
 Azerbaijan +994
 Bahamas +1242
 Bahrain +973
 Bangladesh +880
 Barbados +1246
 Belarus +375
 Belgium +32
 Belize +501
 Benin +229
 Bermuda +1441
 Bhutan +975
 Bolivia +591
 Bosnia & Herzegovina +387
 Botswana +267
 Brazil +55
 British Indian Ocean Territory +246
 British Virgin Islands +1284
 Brunei +673
 Bulgaria +359
 Burkina Faso +226
 Burundi +257
 Cambodia +855
 Cameroon +237
 Canada +1
 Cape Verde +238
 Carribbean Netherlands +599
 Cayman Islands +1345
 Central African Republic +236
 Chad +235
 Chile +56
 China +86
 Christmas Islands +61
 Cocos Islands +61
 Colombia +57
 Comoros +269
 Congo-Kinshasa +243
 Congo-Brazzaville +242
 Cook Islands +682
 Costa Rica +506
 Croatia +385
 Cuba +53
 Curaçao +599
 Cyprus +357
 Czechia +420
 Denmark +45
 Djibouti +253
 Dominica +1767
 Dominican Republic +1
 Ecuador +593
 Egypt +20
 El Salvador +503
 Equatorial Guinea +240
 Eritrea +291
 Estonia +372
 Ethiopia +251
 Falkland Islands +500
 Faroe Islands +298
 Fiji +679
 Finland +358
 France +33
 French Guiana +594
 French Polynesia +689
 Gabon +241
 Gambia +220
 Georgia +995
 Germany +49
 Ghana +233
 Gibraltar +350
 Greece +30
 Greenland +299
 Grenada +1473
 Guadeloupe +590
 Guam +1671
 Guatemala +502
 Guernsey +44
 Guinea +224
 Guinea-Bissau +245
 Guyana +592
 Haiti +509
 Honduras +504
 Hong Kong +852
 Hungary +36
 Iceland +354
 India +91
 Indonesia +62
 Iran +98
 Iraq +964
 Ireland +353
 Isle of Man +44
 Israel +972
 Italy +39
 Ivory Coast +225
 Jamaica +1
 Japan +81
 Jersey +44
 Jordan +962
 Kazakhstan +7
 Kenya +254
 Kiribati +686
 Kosovo +383
 Kuwait +965
 Kyrgyzstan +996
 Laos +856
 Latvia +371
 Lebanon +961
 Lesotho +266
 Liberia +231
 Libya +218
 Liechtenstein +423
 Lithuania +370
 Luxembourg +352
 Macau +853
 Madagascar +261
 Malawi +265
 Malaysia +60
 Maldives +960
 Mali +223
 Malta +356
 Marshall Islands +692
 Martinique +596
 Mauritania +222
 Mauritius +230
 Mayotte +262
 Mexico +52
 Micronesia +691
 Moldova +373
 Monaco +377
 Mongolia +976
 Montenegro +382
 Montserrat +1664
 Morocco +212
 Mozambique +258
 Myanmar +95
 Namibia +264
 Nauru +674
 Nepal +977
 Netherlands +31
 New Caledonia +687
 New Zealand +64
 Nicaragua +505
 Niger +227
 Nigeria +234
 Niue +683
 Norfolk Island +6723
 North Korea +850
 North Macedonia +389
 Northern Mariana Islands +1670
 Norway +47
 Oman +968
 Pakistan +92
 Palau +680
 Panama +507
 Papua New Guinea +675
 Paraguay +595
 Peru +51
 Philippines +63
 Poland +48
 Portugal +351
 Puerto Rico +1
 Qatar +974
 Réunion +262
 Romania +40
 Russia +7
 Rwanda +250
 Saint-Barthélemy +590
 Saint Helena +290
 Saint Kitts & Nevis +1869
 Saint Lucia +1758
 Saint Martin +590
 Saint Pierre & Miquelon +508
 Saint Vincent & Grenadines +1784
 Samoa +685
 San Marino +378
 São Tomé & Príncipe +239
 Saudi Arabia +966
 Senegal +221
 Serbia +381
 Seychelles +248
 Sierra Leone +232
 Singapore +65
 Sint Maarten +1721
 Slovakia +421
 Slovenia +386
 Solomon Islands +677
 Somalia +252
 South Africa +27
 South Korea +82
 South Sudan +211
 Spain +34
 Sri Lanka +94
 Sudan +249
 Suriname +597
 Svalbard & Jan Mayen +47
 Swaziland +268
 Sweden +46
 Switzerland +41
 Syria +963
 Taiwan +886
 Tajikistan +992
 Tanzania +255
 Thailand +66
 Timor-Leste +670
 Togo +228
 Tokelau +690
 Tonga +676
 Trinidad & Tobago +1868
 Tunisia +216
 Turkey +90
 Turkmenistan +993
 Turks & Caicos Islands +1649
 Tuvalu +688
 U.S. Virgin Islands +1340
 Uganda +256
 Ukraine +380
 United Arab Emirates +971
 United Kingdom +44
 United States +1
 Uruguay +598
 Uzbekistan +998
 Vanuatu +678
 Vatican City +39
 Venezuela +58
 Vietnam +84
 Wallis & Futuna +681
 Western Sahara +212
 Yemen +967
 Zambia +260
 Zimbabwe +263
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe,

```
\S\s([^\r\n]*?)\s*\+[0-9]+$
```

might return the country names in the capturing group `$1`.

---

Using lookaround, we can likely write some expression similar to:

```
\S[A-Za-zéã.].*(?=\s\+[0-9])
```

which we would get the second letter using,

```
[A-Za-zéã.]
```

prior to which, there is another `\S`, and we would then bypass the emojis.

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/LJ0cj9/1/)

```js
const regex = /\S\s([^\r\n]*?)\s*\+[0-9]+$/gm;
const str = ` Afghanistan +93
 Åland Islands +358
 Albania +355
 Algeria +213
 American Samoa +1684
 Andorra +376
 Angola +244
 Anguilla +1264`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/2dhU66/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/2dhU66/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Is there a way to get the country name as a direct match, without using a capturing group (perhaps by somehow simply skipping first five characters)? So, something like this, but without the emoji and the space that follows it? https://regex101.com/r/bUEFBg/1/

Comment: This is awesome and it almost covers each! It fails with Réunion, São Tomé & Príncipe, and U.S. Virgin Islands only. Is there a way to include those somehow?

Comment: You ROCK! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend `/^.+?\s(.+?)\+\d+/gm`. Using the multiline flag, this lazily eats characters per line before the first space, then captures until space(s), literal `+` sign and digit(s). If your flag format is consistent, special characters and unusual country names aren't a problem.

```js
const countries = ` Afghanistan +93
 Åland Islands +358
 Albania +355
 Algeria +213
 American Samoa +1684
 Andorra +376
 Angola +244
 Anguilla +1264
 Antigua & Barbuda +1268`;

const reg = /^.+?\s(.+?)\s*\+\d+/gm;
const result = [];

for (let m; m = reg.exec(countries); result.push(m[1]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the country name as a direct match, without using a capturing group (perhaps by somehow simply skipping first five characters)? So, something like this, but without the emoji and the space that follows it? https://regex101.com/r/bUEFBg/1/

Comment: Just curious why that's necessary? Looks like Emma found a way, but it's using a whitelist which might not cover every possibility, so I'd worry about that. I want to do `(?<=[^\x00-\x7F]{4}\s).+?(?=\s\+\d+)` but it's PCRE.

Comment: Sure! For this particular project, I'm using a proprietary no-code platform that runs on JS and has a very limited tooling for working with Regex. It doesn't support capturing groups and one can't write any scripts to touch the extraction process - that part is entirely a black box. I can pretty much just enter the expression and then it's either a hit or a miss. Hope that clarifies things a bit! 

P.S. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Gotcha. That definitely makes it more interesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
/[A-Za-z]\s([a-zA-Z])\s+[0-9]/\1/
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the inclusion of an explanation of the code addressing why and how it solves the problem.